# What is "Accept Rate"?

Tags: support

I apologize if this is not the appropriate place to ask this question, but I'm still finding my way around StackExchange...

On to my question: some users have an "Accept Rate" followed by a percentage underneath their names. What does this mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [main Meta site](http://meta.stackoverflow.com):

See [How does Accept Rate work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/16721/158428) which is part of the [FAQ for Stack Exchange sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7931/158428).

See also [Is 58% accept rate bad?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/88046/158428).

Comment: Very helpful. Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

[This](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16721) is a very relevant meta.SO thread. In particular,

> - The accept rate is the percentage of answers accepted based on the questions asked by the user.
> - The accept rate is calculated on questions that are older than 3 days.
> - The accept rate is heavily cached and can take 24 hours or more to update.
> - The accept rate is only calculated when the user has 4 or more questions.

See the thread for more info.